# にしても and としても, is there a difference?

Tags: grammar, nuances

にしても and としても...Don't they both have a meaning of "even if"? Is there any subtle difference between these two forms?

Comment: This is a good quesion. +1 I've never paid any attention to this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### There is some overlapping meaning. There are also some differences.

I think you may be touching on the deeper subject of the differences between に and と.

Comparing the definitions of に and と shows that they can both be used to refer to the  **result（結果）** of something. に shows the result of *becoming* (dynamic) and と shows the result of *being* (stative).

According to the 大辞林, the **に** in にしても is a form of the word なり which is a contraction of にあり and **is related to なる**.

The **と** in としても is a form of the word たり which is a contraction of てあり, showing completed action and **is related to である**.

```
にしても ⇒ になるとしても ⇒ になっても
としても ⇒ であるとしても ⇒ であっても
```

> **にしても** implies **"even when"** something *becomes* the case
>
> **としても** implies **"even if"** something *is* the case or **"even as"**, **"even for"**.

Obviously there is some overlap in English as well between "even when" and "even if" and I think that this generally agrees with the overlap in Japanese between にしても and としても.

So let's compare two sentences:

> **赤としても黒としても**．．．事実は変わらない

```
（赤であっても黒であっても）
```

You could think of this as "even if it's red, even if it's black", which in context might give you something like this:

- "Whether it's red or black won't change the facts"

Or you could think of it as "even as red, even as black"...

- "Even as red or black, it wouldn't change the facts"

Or you could think of it as "even for red, even for black"...

- "The facts aren't going to change for red or black"

> **赤にしても黒にしても**．．．事実は変わらない

```
（赤になっても黒になっても）
```

This could be thought of as "even when it's red, even when it's black".

In context, maybe something like this:

- "The facts won't change whether we make it red or black"

Or you could think of it as "even for red, even for black"...

- "The facts won't change for red or black"

However, using にしても I think it's difficult to get the meaning "even as" because while として implies taking on a role *as* something （医者として - "*as a doctor*"）, にして can't really fully express the idea of taking on a role.

Just as a final note, I think using the volitional ～しましょう makes the difference between に and と a little clearer.

> 赤**に**しましょう - Let's **make it** red
>
> 赤**と**しましょう - Let's **say that it's** red

Comment: 「にとして can't really fully express the idea of taking on a role.」っていうところ、「にとして」であってます？「にして」って書こうとされました？

Comment: @chocolate あらまぁ…修正しました。毎度！

Answer (score 6):

This is a good question, I personally think. If you google it in Japanese, even Japanese are confused too and I also haven't paid any particular attention to when to use them.

Granted, **[this site](http://www.ravco.jp/cat/view.php?cat_id=4784)** explains as follows.

About にしても

> ＊ A, if not B「たとえBではないにしてもA」：AとBの位置に同じ種類の語句を置き、A, if not B の形で使われる if は even if の意味を持ち、「たとえBではないにしてもA」（もしかしたらBかもしれない）という状況を表します。
>
> *A if not B* type 「たとえBではないにしてもA」：Placing same quality ( quantity? kind? ) of things at the positions of A and B respectively. The "if" used in " A if not B type " means "even if" and in Japanese it is 「たとえBではないにしてもA」, **expressing the situation "it is A but maybe it could be B".**

としても

From the link

> 「それで命を落としたとしても私はそれをやります」
>
> I will do it even if I may die to do it.

Expressing in English "even if".

For example,

My examples are...

> AにしてもBにしても同類｛どうるい｝だよ。
>
> The person A and B are same kind after all, I think.
>
> 私はクビになったとしてもこれを言わねばなりません。
>
> I must say this even if I might be laid of by saying this.

So in short, にしても does not have strong nuance of "even if".

Comment: quanity = quantity? quality (repeated)?

Comment: I'm sorry, quantity, quality, essence etc etc....

Comment: Don't feel sorry, just fix the typo.