# What is the difference between にしては and としては?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, particle-に, particle-と

I know they are both used for comparisons, i.e. "as X...", "for a X....", but I don't understand the difference between them.

Comment: If you don't supply any examples, you are basically asking for any example anyone can produce. That's not really how StackExchange questions should be asked.

Comment: Related questions: [1](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/762/542) [2](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/35948/542)

Answer (score 8):

I think にしては is close to "considering" and としては is close to "as".

For example, 彼は英語の先生にしては、優秀だ (He is talented considering he is a English teacher.) implies he has an ability other than English, but 彼は英語の先生としては、優秀だ (He is talented as a English teacher.) implies the ability of teaching English.

Answer (score 0):

Xにしては is closer to "for" and としては is closer to "as"

```
25歳としてもこれは難しい...
```

*Even as a 25 year old, this is hard*

```
25歳にしてもこれは難しい...
```

*Even for 25 year olds, this is hard*

There is a different level of closeness to the expression, where にしては is more general. In the above example, it would mean "For those who are 25" as opposed to としては which refers to the state of being 25 more than the group of 25 year olds.

It is also worth noting that　として always follows a noun whereas にして can follow a verb or verb clause.

```
初めてケーキを作ったにしては、上手にできましたね。
```

*For somebody who is making a cake for the fist time, she did it very well*

The difference might be easier illuminated if we were to try to translate the following:

"As someone who likes jazz, I'm glad I came to this party."

```
ジャズ好きとしては、このパーティに来てよかった
```

"For people who like jazz, this is a good party."

```
ジャズ好きにしては、このパーティがいい
```

Comment: ジャズが好きな人**にしては** 、このパーティがいい sounds unnatural and makes little sense. Maybe you meant to say ジャズが好きな人**にしてみれば** / ～人にとっては / ～人からすれば ? (I'd use ジャズ[好]{ず}き over ジャズが好きな人 here, by the way)

Comment: noted! the nuance of what I wanted to say was something like "if you're someone who likes X", in which case 〜人にとっては is close, or even 好きなタイプであれば is better.

Answer (score -1):

> A　にしては　B.

Suppose the situation that the fact A generally leads the negative fact B, but not the expected negative fact B but the affirmative fact B is true. Then we say "Aにしては、Bだ。"

> exampl-1: "来日後３か月にしては、彼女の日本語は上手（じょうず）だ。"
>   exampl-2: "来日後１０年にしては、彼の日本語は上手ではない。"
>
> exampl-1: "来日して（まだ）３か月なのだから、日本語は上手ではないだろう。しかし、それにしては、彼女の日本語は上手だ。" = "She has come to Japan only for three months, so I expect she is still not good at speaking Japnese, but contrary to my expectation, she is already a good Japanese speaker."
>   exampl-2: "来日して（もう）１０年なのだから、日本語は上手だろう。しかし、それにしては、彼の日本語は上手ではない。" = "He has come to Japan for ten years long, so I expect he is fairly good at speaking Japanese, but contrary to my expectation, he is poor at speaking Japanese."

"にしては" of the above examples means "although."

---

> A　としては　B.
>
> exampl-3: "来日して３か月の外国人としては、彼女の日本語は上手だ。"
>   exampl-4: "来日して１０年の外国人としては、彼の日本語は上手ではない。"

The above examples are natural and have the same meaning of exapmple-1 and example-2 respectively.

The word "としては" requires a person, an attribute of person (means person itself) or an obstacle, and has more meaning than "にしては."

> "子供が学校でいじめられている。親としては黙っていられない。" = "My child is bullied by his class mates. As his parent, I won't remain silent."
>
> "２５歳としては、大人げない態度だ。"= "２５歳の人間としては、大人げない態度だ。" = "His attitude is poor for the twenty five years adult."
>
> "誕生日にライフルを贈る親がいる。プレゼントとしては不適切だ。" = "Some parents give their child a rifle as a birthday gift. It's extremly inappropriate as a brthday gift."

---

> "A　にしては　Ｂ”
>   Ａ is a situation, and generally A leads negative (affirmative) situation B, but on the contray to such expectation, affirmative (negative) situation B is true.
>
> "Ａ　としては　Ｂ"
>   A is a noun, , and generally A has a negative (affirmative) property B, but on the contray to such expectation, A has an affirmative (negative) property B.

Comment: (長文です)　`意味不明あるいは重箱の隅をつつくような edit も散見されます。主旨が変わってしまうような edit もありました` → 「この編集はいるのか？」とchatや[meta]などで討論できますのでそちらで討論をお願いします。`このサイトでは、editした人にも評価ポイントが付くようになっているのでしょうか？`→強いて言うなら私どものようにReputationが少ない人のreputationが+2されるだけ(少ない人はレビューキューというものに入れられる)です。2k以上あればReputationは*全く* 変化しません。`その旨コメント欄にお書きください`→このサイトの投稿のライセンスはCreative Commons Attribution-Share Alikeですので、自由に編集しても問題ないということになっています。嫌なら使わないという手もあります。あと、「編集すれば？」的なことをコメントするのは駄目っぽいです。"Suggesting corrections that don't fundamentally change the meaning of the post; instead, make or suggest an edit;" - [help]より 詳しいことは[help]に書いてありますのでそちらをご覧下さい。